# How to remove menu items from project menu in eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, menu, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working under eclipse plug-in right now and I am wondering whether it is possible to remove or hide some items from project menu programmatically ?  I mean I can hide project menu items by perspective customization, but how I can do it programmatically, so when eclipse starts I do not see these items.

BTW: I do know about eclipse activities, but I couldn't find the way to remove project menu items in this fashion (it is possible for example to remove search menu items with activities). Maybe you could suggest how to do it with them ?